# Get element real height in Chrome && Firefox with javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, height, dimensions, offsetheight

I have a page full of nested Divs with classes and I want to get the outter div's real height . OffsetHeight worked in IE(!) but not in FireFox and Chrome .

Any body knows in what situation offsetHeight may return wrong value ?

My page is too large and complicated to be posted here. I tried to create a simple code to simulate the situation but it(offsetHeight) worked in the test code (:( ).

OffsetHeight returns wrong( or maybe unexpected to me ) when a div's content's height is more than the div's height . That's another problem .

By the way Jquery returns the same value as offsetHeight does.

Comment: without code example it is hard to judge what's wrong

Comment: You will have to post an example of the problem if you want help.